# WSO2 Identity Server 5.9.0 crashed with the following database error in a cluster setup?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am facing the below error in WSO2 IS 5.9.0.

We are using WSO2 IS in an AWS environment.

WSO2 Node Cloud EC2 Instance Type - t2.small

MySQL Cloud EC2 Instance Type - t2.small

WSO2 Version - 5.9.0
Current Architecture-

2 x WSO2 Node

1 x MySQL Database

1 x Application Load Balancer

Attached WSO2 Carbon logs.

```
TID: [23] [] [2021-02-06 05:12:39,898] [ef8de62b-0cd7-491a-879a-0eb7305b2e15]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder} - Initializing of policy store is started at :  Sat Feb 06 05:12:39 UTC 2021
TID: [23] [] [2021-02-06 05:12:39,904] [ef8de62b-0cd7-491a-879a-0eb7305b2e15]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.store.DefaultPolicyDataStore} - Using Global policy combining algorithm that is defined in configuration file.
TID: [23] [] [2021-02-06 05:12:39,904] [ef8de62b-0cd7-491a-879a-0eb7305b2e15]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder} - Start retrieving policies from org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.store.RegistryPolicyStoreManageModule@7303cb2f at : Sat Feb 06 05:12:39 UTC 2021
TID: [23] [] [2021-02-06 05:12:39,910] [ef8de62b-0cd7-491a-879a-0eb7305b2e15]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder} - Finish retrieving policies from org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.store.RegistryPolicyStoreManageModule@7303cb2f at : Sat Feb 06 05:12:39 UTC 2021
TID: [23] [] [2021-02-06 05:12:39,910] [ef8de62b-0cd7-491a-879a-0eb7305b2e15]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder} - Initializing of policy store is finished at :  Sat Feb 06 05:12:39 UTC 2021
TID: [-1] [] [2021-02-06 08:00:41,235] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler} - Error loading immediate jobs from database. <openjpa-2.2.0-wso2v1-r128166:129108 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Database may be already in use: "Waited for database closing longer than 1 minute". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-199]
FailedObject: SELECT DISTINCT t FROM org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.openjpa.model.HumanTaskJob t WHERE t.nodeId = ?1 AND t.time < ?2 order by t.time [java.lang.String]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4918)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4878)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:110)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:62)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.connect(JDBCStoreManager.java:949)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.getConnection(JDBCStoreManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:413)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:34)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1251)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1007)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:863)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:794)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.openjpa.HumanTaskDAOConnectionImpl.dequeueImmediate(HumanTaskDAOConnectionImpl.java:248)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$2.call(SimpleScheduler.java:344)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$2.call(SimpleScheduler.java:342)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:879)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:828)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler.doLoadImmediate(SimpleScheduler.java:342)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$LoadImmediateTask.run(SimpleScheduler.java:297)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:146)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database may be already in use: "Waited for database closing longer than 1 minute". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:617)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:209)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:178)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:161)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:31)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:336)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:169)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:148)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:87)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.connectInternal(JDBCStoreManager.java:960)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.connect(JDBCStoreManager.java:945)
    ... 25 more
```

My WSO2 Configuration(deployement.toml file)-

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"

[super_admin]
username = "username@wso2.com"
password = "password"
create_admin_account = true

[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true

[user_store]
type = "database"
scim_enabled = true
user_name_attribute = "mail"
username_java_script_regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
username_java_regex='^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}'

[database.identity_db]
type = "mysql"
url= "jdbc:mysql://<SOME_IP>:3306/regdb?useSSL=false"
username = "<SOME_USER>"
password = "<SOME_PASSWORD>"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url= "jdbc:mysql://<SOME_IP>:3306/regdb?useSSL=false"
username = "<SOME_USER>"
password = "<SOME_PASSWORD>"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[[cache.manager]]
name = "LocalClaimInvalidationCache"
timeout = "300"
capacity = "5000"

[carbon_health_check]
enable= true

[keystore.primary]
name = "wso2carbon.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"

[admin_service.wsdl]
enable = true

authentication.authenticator.session_handler.parameters.max_session_count = "100"
```

Comment: Have you shared any H2 databases? If possible can you share the db configurations?

Comment: I have shared my entire config(after editing the question).....I don't intend to use H2 Database anywhere in the config but can you please help me to identify if that is the case